# Executing scripts is the same as dot sourcing?

Tags: powershell

I saw some surprising behavior in powershell recently.

Consider the script c:\scripts\tst1.ps:

```
Set-location c:\
```

Now from powershell:

```
C:\scripts PS> .\tst1.ps1
C:\ PS>
```

Why does the calling shell change to “C:\” according to “set-location”?  shouldnt the “set-location” run from a subshell according to normal scripting rules for other shells like bash?

I thought that you had to “dot source” the script to get this type of behavior???  That is: “. .\tst1.ps1”? What is happening here.

is my powershell misconfigured on my host computer or is this the actual behavior of powershell these days?

Is there a way to reconfigure powershell to get the old behavior that I expect that is similar to bash shell where the script runs in a sub shell and exits and the current directory is uneffected?

Answer (score 0):

You can run your script with the new instance of powershell:

```
C:\scripts PS> powershell .\tst1.ps1
```